# is there a 12 gb memory slot?

Tags: memory, motherboard

my laptop has 12gb i ve seen that in windows linux and even bios.

but when i opened the laptop to figure out i find out that there is only one memory stick and the laptip suport only one memory stick.

but the memort stick has details on it saying 8GB 2666.
so whats happening is it another integreated 4 gb ram on the motherboard or what?

also i buyed the laptop with an extension the place where i buyed from said that its not created with 12gb but they will add it a ram extension manually after buying .

Comment: The most likely case here is 4GB of RAM is soldered on the motherboard, or there is another memory slot in an "unusual" spot, like under the keyboard (I had an HP like that, you couldn't get to the 1st memory slot without removing the keyboard assembly). If you gave more details like what specific make and model of laptop you have, we might be able to give a more accurate answer that isn't guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, the laptop has 4GB of RAM soldered directly to the motherboard.  Hence, the 8GB SODIMM (stick) making the total 12GB.

Without knowing the laptop model, its not possible to say with 100% certainty.  Again, this is likely what is happening.

Check the manufacturer's website, as it should tell you if that model has integrated RAM.

Another possibility would be to use the [memory scanner on Crucial.com](https://www.crucial.com/store/systemscanner?cm_re=homepage-_-hero-_-combobox-scanner-btn), or use [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to scan your memory to get a report.